Issues with Self-Referencing Foreign Key in SQLite
I'm having trouble with a self-referencing foreign key in SQLite. I've created a table to store employee details, where each employee can have a manager who is also an employee. Here's the table definition:
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    Employee_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT,
    Manager_ID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ID) REFERENCES Employees(Employee_ID)
);


I've enabled foreign key constraints with PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON. However, when I insert data with a non-existent Manager_ID, SQLite does not raise an error. Here are the steps I've taken:

Enabled foreign key constraints:

PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;


Created the table:

CREATE TABLE Employees (
    Employee_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT,
    Manager_ID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ID) REFERENCES Employees(Employee_ID)
);


Inserted data:

INSERT INTO Employees (Employee_ID, Name, Manager_ID) VALUES (1, 'Fitch', NULL);
INSERT INTO Employees (Employee_ID, Name, Manager_ID) VALUES (2, 'Alley', 1);

// This should fail because 9 doesn't exist, but doesn't:
INSERT INTO Employees (Employee_ID, Name, Manager_ID) VALUES (6, 'Blake', 9); 

Despite these steps, SQLite does not enforce the foreign key constraint for Manager_ID.
SELECT * FROM Employees

Gives:



Employee_ID
Name
Manager_ID




1
Fitch
NULL


2
Alley
1


6
Blake
9



Are Self-Referencing Foreign Keys supported in SQLite? If so, how do I get it to work?

A foreign key only ensure that the referenced value exists, nothing more

Foreign key constraints in SQLite must be enabled separately for each database connection.

Your code is correct, but as Alexander Patrov explained in the comments, you have to enable foreing key constraints each time you connect to the database.
Dbfiddle
